# How to get data with pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, statistics

I have a problem with getting data.
I have this DataFrame:

[image]

I need to filter by 'fabricante' == 'Kellogs' and get the 'calorias' column, I did this:

[image]

I need the second column (calorias) for introducing in this function:

```
def valor_medio_intervalo(fabricante, variable, confianza):

   subconjunto = None          # Select only the data: (fabricante, variable) from 'cereal_df'

  inicio, final  = None, None  # put the statistical function here.

  return inicio, final
```

And this is my code for the last part:

```
def valor_medio_intervalo(fabricante, variable, confianza):
  
  
  
  subconjunto = cereal_df.loc[cereal_df['fabricante'] == fabricante][variable]
  
  inicio, final  = sm.stats.DescrStatsW(variable).tconfint_mean(alpha = 1-confianza) 

  return inicio, final
```

The error:

[image]

I'm gonna be so appreciative if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You called `DescrStatsW('calorias')`.

But surely you wanted `DescrStatsW(subconjunto)`, right?
I'm just reading https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html
which explains you should pass in
a 1- or 2-column [numpy array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-array_like) or dataframe.

Comment: YESSSSSS, thanks!!
I just got it, with DescrStatsW(subconjunto)

Greetings from Colombia!